# Push objects into an array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm getting a list of objects as a response like this

[image]

As you can see the objects are not in an array. I want to push these objects into an array. I tried the following way

```
this.setState({
   countrydata: this.state.countrydata.push(datasnapshot.val()),
})
```

But it didn't work. What's the correct approach to push these objects into an array?

PS:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const countryCode = this.props.match.params.countryCode;
        var countryName = getName(countryCode);
        var firebaseHeadingref = firebase.database().ref(countryCode);
        firebaseHeadingref.once('value').then(datasnapshot => {
            this.setState({
                countrydata: datasnapshot.val(),
                countryName: countryName,
                loading: false
            })
        });
    }
```

Comment: share you componentDidMount where you are fetching data

Comment: Please post code not images

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
I have not tested below code.

```
componentDidMount=async() =>{
        const countryCode = this.props.match.params.countryCode;
        var countryName = getName(countryCode);
        var firebaseHeadingref = firebase.database().ref(countryCode);
       const datasnapshot = await firebaseHeadingref.once('value');

  this.setState(prevState=>{
   ...prevState,
    countryName,
    countrydata: [...prevState.countrydata, datasnapshot.val()],
    loading: false,
  },()=>console.log("done!"))


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "countrydata" in a dict not an array.
Try to initialize the it as an empty array.

Comment: it is initialized that way. countrydata: [],

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.push` returns the new length of the array after the push, so you are essentially setting the state to a number.

You are not allowed to mutate the array with React state, you need to create a new array containing your new elements:

```
// When updating state based on current state, use the function form of setState.
this.setState(state => {
   countrydata: [...state.countrydata, datasnapshot.val()],
})
```

This is assuming `countryData` is indeed an array, which from your screenshot, it appears to not (it seems to be an object), so you may be set something wrong somewhere along the way (or `datasnapshot.val()`) doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for-in` to loop through the object or use `Object.keys()`.

```
const data = datasnapshot.val();
const countrydata = [];

for (let key in data) {
  countrydata.push(data[key])
}

// using Object.keys()

Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => countrydata.push({ [key]: data[key]}))

this.setState({
  countrydata
})
```

```js
const data = {

place1: { name: 'One'},
place2: { name: 'Two'},
place3: { name: 'Three'},
};


const countrydata = [];

for (let key in data) {
  countrydata.push({ [key]: data[key] });
}

console.log(countrydata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
const keys = Object.keys(countryData);  // array of the keys ["place_1", ...]
const array = Array(keys.length);       // Prepares the output array of the right size
for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
  const country = countryData[keys[i]]; // get the next country object
  country.key = keys[i];                // add the key into the object if you need it
  array[i] = country;                   // store the value into the array at index 'i'
}
// array now is [ {key: "place_1", description: "Sigiriya Rock Fortress"}, ...]
this.setState({countryDataArray: array});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the response data from firebase to an array like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const countryCode = this.props.match.params.countryCode;
  var countryName = getName(countryCode);
  var firebaseHeadingref = firebase.database().ref(countryCode);
  firebaseHeadingref.once('value').then(datasnapshot => {

    const countryData = datasnapshot.val();

    const countryDataArray = [];

    for (const key in countryData) {
      countryDataArray.push({ key, ...countryData[key]});
    }

    this.setState({
      countrydata: countryDataArray,
      countryName: countryName,
      loading: false
    })
  });
}
```